# extracting numbers from filenames with batch (windows)

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I don't know *anything* about batch scripting, but I have to do one task.
In file

```
123abc.txt
456def.txt
789ggg.txt
```

I have to extract the initial numeric part from the filename and process the file only if the number is higher than a given base number.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in (%TEMP%\out.tmp) do (
    set "var=%%f" & set /A "num=var"
    echo %num%
    rem if %num% GEQ %vers% do something
)
```

The value of num is always random, it seems it's always set to the first value it finds.

Can anyone help me showing an example, please?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Whenever you change a value of a variable within a closed block of parenthesis, you have to

1) place `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your script (common place is beneath the `@echo off` line) and
2) change `%num%` to `!num!` .

Delayed is needed because the whole block of the if-statement is calculated at once -> changing a value within without delayed expansion will not be seen as such as it got calculated before.
With delayed expansion however you tell the program, that it has to calculate this part again when it reaches there.

And eventhough you do not know anything about batch scripting I am sure you can do it! Think of a logic your program has to follow and then search how to implement each individual part of it in batch.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from geisterfurz007 point there is also the problem that you can't simply `set /a` a var containing letters into another var. Provided the line always begin with a number you could take all letters as delimiters and thus cut them off. Instead off using delayed expansion you may use pseudo call's but have to double the percent signs then.

```
(Echo 123abc.txt
 Echo 456def.txt
 Echo 789ggg.txt
) >%TEMP%\out.tmp

Echo off 
for /F "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %%f in (%TEMP%\out.tmp) do (
    set "var=%%f"
    call set /A "num=%%var%%"
    call echo The number part is: %%num%%
    rem if %num% GEQ %vers% do something
)
```

```
Output
The number part is: 123
The number part is: 456
The number part is: 789
```

**Edit** Or better do simply

```
for /F "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %%f in (%TEMP%\out.tmp
  ) do if %%f GEQ %vers% do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 IF /i "a" gtr "%%a" IF "%%a" geq "0" IF "%%a" gtr "%vers%" ECHO DO something with "%%a"
)
```

Sadly, there's a number of significant things you haven't told us. Are the files specifically in the form 3digits-three-letters.txt? Will `vers` always be of the same length as the length of the leading-digits string?

If so, the above exploits the ASCII order - the first letter must be <`A` and > '0' (which only allows digits) so we detect a numeric leader. If all of the files with a numeric leader have the same length leader, then ASCII order is sufficient.

But - that's only a guess. Need more information about the files and `vers`